# Go Web Service - Undefined type has no field or method

Tags: go

I am trying to consolidate routing functionality within a web service. The package main has two files of concern, `route.go` and `main.go`.

Within `route.go` I am defining routing as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/justinas/alice"
    "net/http"
)

func (app *Application) Routes() http.Handler {
    standardMiddleware := alice.New(app.logRequest)

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/ping", helpers.Ping)

    return standardMiddleware.Then(mux)
}
```

Within `main.go` I am trying to execute the application as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Application struct {
    errorLog *log.Logger
}

func main() {
    addr := flag.String("addr", ":8080", "HTTP Network Address")
    flag.Parse()

    errorLog := log.New(os.Stderr, "ERROR\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)

    app := &Application{
        errorLog: errorLog,
    }

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:     *addr,
        ErrorLog: errorLog,
        Handler:  app.Routes(),
    }

    err := srv.ListenAndServe()
    errorLog.Fatal(err)
}
```

When I execute the program I get the following error: `app.Routes undefined (type *Application has no field or method Routes)`

I'm not sure why the method isn't registering correctly?

Comment: How do you execute the program?

Comment: It won't compile. I attempt to execute here: ` go run cmd/web/main.go
` Apologies where have I gone wrong? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Seems like your `Application` struct doesn't have `logRequest` field either

Comment: I've defined that elsewhere, I can add if that would be helpful? It's not throwing an error for `logRequest` at the moment.

Comment: `go run cmd/web/main.go` is your problem. That's now how `go run` should be used. Better to use `go build` or `go install` on the package path (or without any argument for the current directory). If for some reason you insist on using `go run`, with recent versions of Go you can use `go run .` to build and run the package in the current directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
go run cmd/web/main.go cmd/web/route.go
```

`go run` takes file or files as input. It compiles only those file or files before running. So you need to add `route.go` file as input otherwise the method you declared in it, will be undefined.

`go run ./cmd/web` also works.

**Update:**

If you're in the same directory of `main.go`, just use:

```
go run .
```